# Can't burn fuse bits on ATMega168 with Arduino Uno as ISP

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude, atmega

I have an ATMega168 that I am programming via my Arduino Uno as ISP. I can burn the bootloader and transfer a hex file just fine, but I can't seem to be able to change the fuse bits. I found a lot of people having similar problems, but most still weren't resolved after many years or can't connect to their chip at all.

A weird thing I notice is that my ATMega is recognized as an 328p all the time. I know they're practically identical, but nothing works when I change settings to an 168, I always have to set it to 328p. Avrdude tells me the signature is wrong, whenever I try it with 168. Might that already be an indicator for something being wrong!? I ordered a 168 and it's printed on the chip, so it should be an actual 168.

Furthermore I noticed that I can only use the Baud rate of 115200, but I read that only 19200 should be correct and when I use that I get no response as well.

This is the command I'm trying to use:

```
avrdude -Cavrdude.conf -patmega328p -PCOM3 -carduino -b115200 -U efuse:w:0x00:m -U hfuse:w:0xDD:m -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m
```

And the response I get is:

```
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x00 != 0xdd
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

I tried different software and different USB cables, to no avail.

If anyone could provide any direction I can try and look for a solution or mistakes I might have made, I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer on another forum. I was missing a **10μF capacitor** between the Ground and Reset of the Arduino. Not a single documentation, image or video I saw mentioned that. Everything works fine now.

Comment: so you could burn the bootloader without the capacitor, but not set fuses?

Comment: [This official doc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Tutorial/ArduinoISP) mentions the capacitor in the text. Though it is not very clear and is not shown in the wiring diagrams. The official Arduino docs are often not that good

Comment: @Juraj It seems that I was addressing the ATMega328p on the Arduino itself the whole time so I probably uploaded everything to that instead of the 168.

Comment: @chrisl Thanks for pointing that out! Apparently it's also sufficient to directly bridge the +5V and Reset pin, but I haven't treid that, yet.

Comment: it is not possible to burn bootloader to the as ISP programmer Arduino

Comment: Alright. The burning process went through without error, though, and I also got verification at the end. So no idea where that data went, was just my guessing :)